# Canonically isomorphic

Tags: harmonic-analysis, canonical-transformation

I am currently working through the exercises in 'Principles of Harmonic Analysis'

For a closed subgroup B of the LCA-group A and a closed subgroup L of $\widehat{A}$.

Let $B^{\bot}=\{\chi\in\widehat{A}:\chi(B)=1\}$

$L^{\bot}=\{x\in{A}:\delta_{x}(L)=1\}$

where $\delta$ is the Pontryagin map.

How do you show that $B^{\bot}$ is canonically isomorphic to $\widehat{A/B}$, $(B^{\bot})^{\bot}=B$ and $\widehat{A}/B^{\bot}$ is canonically isomorphic to $\widehat{B}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on this problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Saying $B^{\bot}=\{x\in{A}:\delta_{x}(L)=1\}$ makes no sense unless you say something about what you mean by $L$.

Comment: sorry, I made an error which I have now corrected.